# Вопрос по общей теории Python. Чем оператор отличается от функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, теория

Заметил разделение на функции и операторы в питоне.

Нашел такие определения в книге A Byte of Python:

Функции – это многократно используемые фрагменты программы. Они позволяют дать имя определённому блоку команд с тем, чтобы впоследствии запускать этот блок по указанному имени в любом месте программы и сколь угодно много раз. Это называется вызовом функции.

Операторы – это некий функционал, производящий какие-либо действия, который может быть представлен в виде символов, как например +, или специальных зарезервированных слов. Операторы могут производить некоторые действия над данными, и эти данные называются операндами. В нашем случае 2 и 3 – это операнды.

Как мне кажется определения в чем то схожи, так в чем главные отличия?

Comment: Функция - явно не наименьшая часть, может и тысячи строк кода занимать

Comment: А больше отличий нету?

Comment: Смотрите стандарт используемого языка, там должны быть однозначные определения, а не абстрактные с википедии

Comment: Под "инструкция или оператор" видимо имеют в виду "statement", то есть, очень грубо говоря, отдельную строчку кода, выполняющую какое-то действие (типа `print("Hello world!")`).

Comment: Ладно тогда более конкретно под язык поменяю вопрос.

Comment: Если привести аналогии. Так вот Инструкция или оператор - это слова в языке. а Функции - предложения.

Comment: @Diareich я просил стандарт, а вы книжку процитировали :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если привести аналогии.
`Инструкция` или `оператор` - это слова в языке.
`Функции` - предложения.

то есть `Функции` - состоят из `Инструкций` и/или `операторов`, обратное не верно

Comment: есть перегрузка операторов

Comment: Перегузка или нет, человеку нужно объяснить, что есть атомарность (не делимость) в конструкциях языка. Если язык позволяет разделить/переопределить слово на части то какие проблемы. Мало что ли языков на планете?

Comment: `array.append(valueToBeInserted)` vs `array += [valueToBeInserted]`.
О какой атомарности речь?

Comment: думаю об этой =

Comment: На уровне процессора `=` в питоне скорее всего не атомарно.
Если интересно, могу изложить подробней.
Или речь о другой атомарности?

Comment: я понимаю что в различных языках по разному. Я привел аналогию.

Answer (score 3):

Всё достаточно расплывчато, учитывая, что есть перегрузка операторов -- вызов функции выглядит как оператор:
https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/peregruzka-operatorov.html

Это больше вопрос читаемости: `add(a,multiply(b,c))` и `a+b*c`.

Хотя обычно оператором обозначается некое боллее примитивное действие.

В некоторых языках разницы нет:
`a --==***==-- b` и `a.--==***==--(b)` -- одинаковые вызовы метода `--==***==--`

При перегрузке операторов стоит знать меру -- разобраться, что делает `a.--==***==--(b)` сложнее, чем `a.shakeAndPut(b)`

Comment: Из-за того что всё расплывчато я и уходил в другую аналогию. Слово тоже может целым предложением. Здесь идея объяснить что исходит откуда. А не вводить в заблуждение

Comment: Да, у процессора фиксированный набор инструкций, которые он обычно выполняет очень быстро. И хороший программист примерно представляет, во что превращается его код на ЯВУ.

Answer (score 2):

Хочу добавить, что функции не всегда многократно используются, и их нельзя использовать сколько угодно раз. Во первых, есть такая забавная штука, называется lambda функция. Это безыменная одноразовая функция. А во вторых, функция можно использовать только 1000 раз в программе, но это можно изменить

Comment: не 1000 раз в программе, а глубина стека по умолчанию, наверно.
т. е. , например, если функцию долго вызывать из самой себя -- будет ошибка

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov Хочу добавить: можно изменить макс. глубину вот так -- `import sys;sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)` , но это не вседга безопасно. см на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it)

Answer (score 2):

Из *математической* точки зрения [оператор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) то же самое, как [функция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)), только форма другая.

Например, для бинарных операторов:

```
a оператор b
```

возможно применить (в математике) запись

```
оператор(a, b)
```

(и даже так называемую [польскую запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) `оператор a b`, когда скобки совсем не нужны).

В языках программирования обычно не употребляются обе формы (функция и оператор) для той же самой операции, и когда употребляются, их имени чаще всего *разны* (например `+` и `sum`).

Тоже, для операторов обычно используются *специальные символы* (`+`, `/`, `**` и тд.), а для функций (главным образом) *буквы и цифры.*

Comment: С математической точки зрения, есть понятие как набор операторов - Аксиоматика и Функции - теоремы